# XQuery - Trying to translate SQL query to Xquery (group by, sum, inner join) and miserably failing

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, inner-join, xquery

So I am trying to do this:

"Generate a table of all the continents and the sum of the areas of all those lakes that contain
at least one island for each continent. If a lake is in a country that is situated on several
continents, the appropriate share of the lake area should be counted for each of those
continents.
"

using this XML database:https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml

I already have a SQL query that does this:

```
WITH LakesWithIslands AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT IslandIn.lake, Lake.area, geo_lake.country
    FROM ((IslandIn
    INNER JOIN Lake ON IslandIn.lake = Lake.name)
    INNER JOIN geo_lake ON IslandIn.lake = geo_lake.lake)
    WHERE IslandIn.lake IS NOT NULL
    ) 

SELECT B.continent, SUM(B.percentage * A.area / 100)
    FROM LakesWithIslands as A
    INNER JOIN encompasses as B ON A.country = B.country
    GROUP BY B.continent;
```

But now I am trying to translate this SQL query into an Xquery.

XQuery code:

```
let $doc := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial
let $lakesWithIslands := $doc/island/data(@lake)
let $lakeData := (
  for $l in $doc/lake
  let $lakeId := $l/data(@id)
  where $lakeId = $lakesWithIslands
  return <lake id="{$lakeId}" country="{$l/data(@country)}" area="{$l/data(area)}"     ></lake>
)
let $countryData :=(
  for $c in $doc/country
  let $countrycode := $c/data(@car_code)
  let $encompassData := $c/encompassed
    for $e in  $encompassData
    let $continent := $e/data(@continent)
    let $percent := $e/data(@percentage)
    return <country country="{$countrycode}" continent="{$continent}" percentage="{$percent}"></country>
)

for $l in $lakeData,
    $c in $countryData
let $lCountry := $l/data(@country)
let $lArea := $l/data(@area)
let $cContinent := $c/data(@continent)
let $cCountry := $c/data(@country)
let $percent := $c/data(@percentage) 
where $lCountry = $cCountry
group by $cContinent
return <item continent="{$cContinent}" area="{sum(($percent*$lArea) div 100)}"></item>
```

I am failing at the last step (last for-loop) and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I just get an error that says "[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: ("25", "25")".

I am pretty sure that I am doing the last for-loop completely wrong but I can't figure out how to use inner join, group by and sum together in Xquery.

Please help.

EDIT: I feel bad for posting so many question here regarding Xquery today but I am just having a real hard time wrapping my head around the practical parts of Xquery. Excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XQuery is "less declarative" than SQL in the sense that your code often has to follow the structure of the data more than in a typical `SELECT`/`FROM`/`WHERE` SQL query. Joins can be performed naturally through nested FLWOR expressions, not only by gathering all data in pseudo-tables and then matching those.

For your concrete task it is easiest to iterate over all countries and the continents they are on, gather the relevant lakes and the part of their area for each country-continent combination and then group those by continent:

```
declare variable $lakes-with-islands :=
    for $lake-id in distinct-values(doc('mondial.xml')//island/@lake)
    return doc('mondial.xml')//lake[@id = $lake-id];

for $country in doc('mondial.xml')//country
let $lakes-in-country :=
    $lakes-with-islands[contains-token(@country, $country/@car_code)]
for $encompassed in $country/encompassed
let $proportional-areas :=
    for $lake in $lakes-in-country
    return $lake/area * $encompassed/@percentage div 100
group by $continent := $encompassed/@continent
return <continent name="{$continent}">{sum($proportional-areas)}</continent>
```

This returns:

```
<continent name="europe">7875.5</continent>
<continent name="asia">24721.34</continent>
<continent name="africa">206610</continent>
<continent name="australia">242.66</continent>
<continent name="america">155036.7</continent>
```

This country lakes that are shared between multiple countries multiple times, but that seems to be intended by the problem description(?).

`$lakes-with-islands` is declared as a static variable so that it is not touched by the `group by` clause.

Comment: Just one quick clarification about the code. What value is "@country" in the "contains-token" function? Is it shorthand for $lakes-with-islands/@country? I am assuming that "@country" contains the country attribute for EACH lake in $lake-with-islands...right?

Comment: Inside the predicate `[...]` the *context item* `.` is bound to the current item to be tested. The context item can also be omitted, so a naked attribute step `@country` is equivalent to `./@country` and therefore performed on the current item. `$lakes-with-islands[contains-token(@country, $country/@car_code)]` is therefore equivalent to `for $lake in $lakes-with-islands  where contains-token($lake/@country, $country/@car_code)  return $lake`.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks!